# Puppeteer cluster sometimes cannot start in k8s

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm using `puppeteer` with `puppeteer-cluster`, this is deployed on k8s and everything works great.
The only problem I'm having is that sometimes the pod won't start, and throws this exception:

```
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to launch browser, error message: read ECONNRESET
    at Cluster.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Cluster.js:107:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-cluster/dist/Cluster.js:6:65)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

followed by:

```
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

and:

```
(node:24) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This doesn't affect me functionally considerably, as k8s just creates a new pod (which works fine), but I'd like to understand what happens, and if I can fix it.

Cluster initialization code:

```
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
      concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
      maxConcurrency: Constants.CONFIG.URL_CONCURRENCY,
      retryLimit: Constants.CONFIG.CLUSTER_INTERNAL_RETRIES,
      timeout: Constants.CONFIG.MAX_TIMEOUT
      puppeteerOptions: { ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, args: ["--no-sandbox"] }
    });
```

versions:

```
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "puppeteer-cluster": "^0.18.0",
```

Comment: Can you share your k8s configuration/script in a github repo?

Comment: And, does it work fine without the cluster?

Comment: without the cluster - I have not observed this error, but it happens rarely even with the cluster, so that is not a good indication

Comment: k8s config - sorry, I can't share it, but if you have a specific question I can try to answer

Comment: I don't believe I'm doing anything which is not standard

Comment: You can try to make a repository which we can use to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206002/discussion-between-orirab-and-md-abu-taher).